# How to do a very special grouping in Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I have a table as this in Oracle SQL

[image]

Could you please share me some light on how to connect all activities so that their period is connected into one row so that the result looks like following in Oracle SQL:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do your time intervals have gaps? Solution will be different in this case.

Comment: There is always 1 sec gap between each period. But true that for this particular task we can simply say as no gap.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming there are no gaps, then you can use `lead()` and `lag()` -- without aggregation:

```
select activity, start_date,
       coalesce(lead(start_date) over (order by start_date) - interval '1' second,
                max_end_date
               )
from (select t.*,
             lag(activity) over (order by start_date) as prev_activity,
             max(end_date) over () as max_end_date
      from t
     ) t
where prev_activity is null or prev_activity <> activity;
```

Note:  I think it is a very bad idea to have the end time be one second before midnight.  I think your data should be structured with dates -- with no time components -- for both the start and end.  Then, comparisons would use `<` for the end time.

Comment: In the top select you've misspelled max_end_date as max(end_date), so it would not work because of absence of group by

Comment: Hi Gordon, Thanks for your note, I agree with you. But in my situation, this is kind of the only solution, Because actually the table is a temporal table for a report server. So that the end date needs to be greater than the start date. This query is to fix some issues caused by the temporal table. For temporal table, there is a criteria that the start period, needs to be greater than the end period. However, if I put the end date as the start date of the next period, I will return two rules when i query as the start date of next period. That's why I cannot do this. Thanks for your advice! :)

Comment: Of course, if you have any better idea. Please share with me. I am very happy to learn from them too, Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's a gap & island problem - You can try the below

```
select activity, min(startdate) as startdate,max(enddate) as enddate
from 
(select *,row_number() over(order by startdate)-
     row_number() over(partition by col1 order by startdate) as grp
)A
group by activity,grp
```

Comment: Hi, I can't simply group by activity, as otherwise, my result will be two lines only - Activity for working with be between 01 JAN to 13 JAN and have overlapped with the Day off period. That's why I say I need to do a very special way of grouping.

Comment: @ELeung, I've updated the answer - you can check. It's a gap and island problem

Comment: Let me try it an get up back you ASAP

Answer (score 0):

It's a difficult to cover all cases just based on 4 sample records. You could also use [Pattern Recognition With MATCH_RECOGNIZE](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E12839_01/apirefs.1111/e12048/pattern_recog.htm#CQLLR1531)

```
WITH t(ACTIVITY, start_date, end_date) AS ( 
    SELECT 'Working', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-01 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-02 23:59:59' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Working', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-03 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-10 23:59:59' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Day Off', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-10 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-12 23:59:59' FROM dual UNION ALL
    SELECT 'Working', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 00:00:00', TIMESTAMP '2020-01-13 23:59:59' FROM dual)
SELECT *
FROM t
MATCH_RECOGNIZE (
    ORDER BY end_date
    MEASURES 
        FINAL MIN(start_date) AS start_date,
        FINAL MAX(end_date) AS end_date,
        FINAL LAST(ACTIVITY) AS ACTIVITY
    PATTERN (a act*)
    DEFINE 
        act AS PREV(act.ACTIVITY) = act.ACTIVITY
)
```